# Jquery Carrousel works only if I press CTRL+SHIFT+J

Tags: jquery

I dont know why my [jQuery Carousel](http://www.anonymousica.it/nascosta/index.php) section "Film" works only if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. In the demo page or here this is not necessary:

http://www.anonymousica.it/nascosta/prova.php

Comment: please initialize your slider after animation complete. May be timeout can help you in this situation.

Comment: Can you please help me a bit with code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to initialize slider in menu function like this?

```
function menu(id) {
    $("#col-sx").click(function () {
        //....Existing Code
        setTimeout(function(){  $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you from home go to Film, it works. If you from home go first in one other section and then to Film, it doesn't work. Also Carrousel doesn't work fine: if you check, it loads lots of slides together.